# Python how to merge two csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, merge

Im trying to merge two csv files (a and b) into one (c). The csv files look like this:

--- CSV A ---

```
Field_1, Key
a0     , k0
a1     , k1
a2     , k2
a3     , k0
a4     , k2
a5     , k0
```

--- CSV B ---

```
Key, Field_2, Field_3
k0 , b0     , c0
k1 , b1     , c1
k2 , b2     , c2
k3 , b3     , c3
```

--- Expected CSV C (merged csv) ---

```
Field_1, Key, Field_2, Field_3
a0     , k0 , b0     , c0
a1     , k1 , b1     , c1
a2     , k2 , b2     , c2
a3     , k0 , b0     , c0
a4     , k2 , b2     , c2
a5     , k0 , b0     , c0
```

So basically the fields from the csv b that matches the key of csv a should be joined to get csv c. But instead Im getting the next merged fields empty

--- Actual CSV C ---

```
Field_1, Key, Field_2, Field_3
a0     , k0 ,        , 
a1     , k1 ,        , 
a2     , k2 ,        , 
a3     , k0 ,        , 
a4     , k2 ,        , 
a5     , k0 ,        ,
```

This is the code Im trying to use to merge this fields. But as I said, I am unable to get the data from the csv b merged, I only get the headers.

```
a = pd.read_csv("a.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("b.csv").rename(columns={'Key': ' Key'})
result = a.merge(b, on=" Key", how="left")
result.to_csv("c.csv", index=False)
```

So how would I do so I get the data from csv b merged correctly? Thanks.

Comment: you can just use `csv.DictReader()` in csv module for that, read the python doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have spaces(_) in your key field. In a.csv you have "_key" (e.g. "*k0") and in b.csv you have "key*" (e.g. "k0_") so the keys does not match. If you remove the blank spaces in the csv file this code works:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("a.csv",sep=",")
b = pd.read_csv("b.csv",sep=",")

pd.merge(a,b,on="Key",how="left")
```

You can use skipinitialspace=True during import for a.csv as the whitespace is in front like so :

```
a = pd.read_csv("a.csv",sep=",",skipinitialspace=True)
```

or you define a function that strips any whitespace and apply it at the import:

```
def trim(dataset):

    trim = lambda x: x.strip() if type(x) is str else x #Stripping whitespaces in values

    dataset = dataset.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip()) #Stripping whitespaces in colnames

    return dataset.applymap(trim)

a = trim(pd.read_csv("a.csv",sep=","))
b = trim(pd.read_csv("b.csv",sep=","))
```

Comment: Thanks for the skipinitialspace=True but I forgot to add a pice of code. I renamed that column to avoid that error. In the code the column in b is renamed to match the one from a when reading b. The problem isnt because of the columns

Comment: I tried adding skipinitialspace=True and it worked, thanks, still not sure why I wasnt working before as I had renamed the column so that it matched the name of the other.

Comment: The values also containted initial (a.csv) and trailing (b.csv) whitespaces, so when i tried it there was a key error first (because of the whitespaces in the column names) and then the keys could not be matched because of the whitespaces contained by the values

Comment: That explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just change `how` property to `outer`.

```
result = a.merge(b, on=" Key", how = "outer")
```

*left* use only `keys` from left frame, similar to a SQL left outer join; preserve key order

Comment: When using outer I get all data of csv b below a instead of them combined together.

Comment: @PSM, yes, because `outer` use union of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL full outer join; sort keys lexicographically

Comment: @PSM, you can use `sort=False` in order to prevent sorting of final data.

Comment: Using outer I still dont get the same CSV C I described before but with CSV B attached below CSV A. So A line of CSV C will still look like   a0,k0,, instead of a0,k0,b0,c0

Answer (score 1):

The merged data is empty because of incorrect key. As per your data keys in b.csv is different from keys in a.csv as it contains an extra space.

Your code will work for these data

**a.csv**

`Field_1,Key
a0, k0
a1, k1
a2, k2
a3, k0
a4, k2
a5, k0`

**b.csv**

`Key, Field_2, Field_3
k0, b0, c0
k1, b1, c1
k2, b2, c2
k3, b3, c3`

Comment: Forgot to add to my code that I renamed that column to avoid that error. In the code the column in b is renamed to match the one from a